# Giving parameters for an event listener function in JS

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, addeventlistener

I have a function (`doUpload_reply`) which has `eventListeners` in it. My problem is when I want to use the `completeHandler_reply` I need to specify a reply id, too. So I gave the id as a parameter in an anonymouse function but did not work for me. I don't know what can be the problem or if there any other solutions to give a parameter for an event listener function I'd very happy.
**Code:**
The `doUpload_reply` function

```
function doUpload_reply(id,e){
    var file = _(id).files[0];
    if(file.name == ""){
        return false;       
    }
    if(file.type != "image/jpeg" && file.type != "image/gif" && file.type != "image/png" && file.type != "image/jpg"){
        alert("That file type is not supported.");
        return false;
    }
    _("triggerBtn_SP_reply").style.display = "none";
    _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply_"+e).innerHTML = '<img src="images/rolling.gif" width="30" height="30">';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("stPic_reply", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){
        completeHandler_reply.call(this,e);
    }, false ); // Here is the problem when I want to give 'e' as a 
                // parameter for the completeHandler_reply function (e is the id)
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler_reply, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler_reply, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "php_parsers/photo_system.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Is there any way to pass an argument through `completeHandler_reply` like I did in the `doUpload_reply` function?
The `completeHandler_reply` function is here:

```
function completeHandler(event){
    var data = event.target.responseText;
    var datArray = data.split("|");
    if(datArray[0] == "upload_complete_reply"){
        hasImage = datArray[1];
        _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = '<img src="tempUploads/'+datArray[1]+'" class="statusImage" />';
    } else {
        _("uploadDisplay_SP").innerHTML = datArray[0];
        _("triggerBtn_SP").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

And I get a JS error in my console: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.completeHandler_reply (user.php?u=Frankli Mark&pn=1:1087)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (user.php?u=Frankli Mark&pn=1:1078)*

Comment: `but did not work for me`. Why?

Comment: It simply does not get the parameter.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(e)` at the top of `doUpload_reply` to check if `e` is undefined. Also include the `completeHandler_reply` function.

Comment: `e` is defined, it gives me back the right number. I tried console.log directly before the `completeHandler_reply` so probably the function does not get the parameter `e`.

Comment: I think the problem is in your `completeHandler_reply` function, can you edit your question and include the code of that, too?